# NLS Function By Group

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, nls

I have a dataset where I want to apply non linear least squares by group. This is a continuation to my previous question: 
[NLS Function - Number of Iterations Exceeds max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708868/nls-function-number-of-iterations-exceeds-max)

The dataset looks like this:

```
df
x        y    GRP
0        0      1
426   9.28      1
853   18.5      1
1279  27.8      1
1705  37.0      1
2131  46.2      1
0        0      2
450   7.28      2
800   16.5      2
1300  30.0      2
2000  40.0      2
2200  48.0      2
```

If I were to do this with one group it would be like this:

```
df1<-filter(df, GRP==1)

a.start <- max(df1$y)
b.start <- 1e-06
control1 <- nls.control(maxiter= 10000,tol=1e-02, warnOnly=TRUE)
nl.reg <- nls(y ~ a * (1-exp(-b * x)),data=df1,start= 
list(a=a.start,b=b.start),
           control= control1)
coef(nl.reg)[1]
coef(nl.reg)[2]

> coef(nl.reg)[1]
       a 
5599.075 
> coef(nl.reg)[2]
       b 
3.891744e-06
```

I would then do the same thing for GRP2. I want my final output to look like this:

```
x        y    GRP                       a                       b
0        0      1                5599.075            3.891744e-06
426   9.28      1                5599.075            3.891744e-06
853   18.5      1                5599.075            3.891744e-06
1279  27.8      1                5599.075            3.891744e-06
1705  37.0      1                5599.075            3.891744e-06
2131  46.2      1                5599.075            3.891744e-06
0        0      2    New Value for a GRP2    New Value for b GRP2     
450   7.28      2    New Value for a GRP2    New Value for b GRP2
800   16.5      2    New Value for a GRP2    New Value for b GRP2
1300  30.0      2    New Value for a GRP2    New Value for b GRP2
2000  40.0      2    New Value for a GRP2    New Value for b GRP2
2200  48.0      2    New Value for a GRP2    New Value for b GRP2
```

Ideally I think dplyr would be the best way but I can't figure out how to do it. This is what I think it will probably look like:

```
control1 <- nls.control(maxiter= 10000,tol=1e-02, warnOnly=TRUE)
b.start <- 1e-06

df %>%
  group_by(GRP) %>%
  do(nlsfit = nls( form = y ~ a * (1-exp(-b * x)), data=., 
start= list( a=max(.$y), b=b.start),
      control= control1) ) %>%
  list(a = coef(nlsfit)[1], b = coef(nlsfit)[2])
```

Error:

```
 in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

Not really sure how to do this though and any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: There is an error in your code `df1<-filter(df, GRP=1)` probably should be `df1<-filter(df, GRP==1)`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I didn't actually run that part. Was just showing it for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @42 does the question make sense?

Comment: It does. Does the answer need to be tidyversical? I find that environment rather difficult to understand much of the time.

Comment: Nope it just needs to by dynamic where it doesn't matter how many groups there are. My actual dataset has 5000 groups making the total dataset close to 1MM rows. Dplyr is usually the fastest with handling that from what I've been researching.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate (despite it having an utterly cryptic title) with a tidyverse answer by @Hack-R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220231/error-results-are-not-data-frames-at-positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially got the same error message (re: not finding object 'y' in `nls`) as I did with a `tidyverse` stab when initially attempting to use the `lapply-split-function` paradigm and went searching for: "[r] using nls inside function". I've changed my original use of `attach` to `list2env`:

```
sapply(  split( df , df$GRP), function(d){ dat <- list2env(d)
    nlsfit <- nls( form = y ~ a * (1-exp(-b * x)), data=dat, start= list( a=max(y), b=b.start),
          control= control1) 

list(a = coef(nlsfit)[1], b = coef(nlsfit)[2])} )
#---

  1            2            
a 14.51827     441.5489     
b 2.139378e-06 -6.775562e-06
```

You also get warnings that you were expecting. These could be suppressed with `suppressWarnings( ... )`

One of the suggestions was to use `attach`. Which I then did with extreme reluctance, since I have often warned newbies not to ever use `attach`. But here it seemed to force a local environment to be constructed. I'm more comforatable with list2env as a mechaism to satisfy nls. The top of the code for `nls` was what led me to that choice:

```
if (!is.list(data) && !is.environment(data)) 
    stop("'data' must be a list or an environment")
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm away from my computer until the morning but will attempt to transpose the results so they look like the final output in the question.

Comment: The structure of the result is a 4 item list with a length-2 dimension. It does respond satisfactorily to the `t` function.

Comment: I tested this out this morning and it is giving me the error of `Error in nls(form = y ~ a * (1 - exp(-b * x)), data = dat,  : 
  object 'y' not found`

Comment: When I change it to be `dat$y` and `dat$x` in the model, it throws me a new error stating: `Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`

Comment: Still working for me. Using `$` inside formulas is generally a bad thing. And you have not included full code and data so are violating the SO rule requiring [MCVE] for questions about errors. The error makes me suspect you are again using perfect data, and you've been warned about that issue.

Comment: Ok thanks, will take a look further into why this is happening. Appreciate the help!

Comment: By the way, I figured out what was happening. There were cases where y equaled 0. When that happened it through the error. So instead, I added disturbance or random noise to make it not be equal to 0. This ended up not throwing the error. Your code also ran extremely fast for a 1MM row dataset with over 5000 groups. Appreciate the help!

Comment: When you transpose it and then convert it to a dataframe like this: `df1<-as.data.frame(t(output))`, the values are still a part of a list. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730383/convert-list-values-within-a-dataframe-to-single-level-numbers