# Write a Data.Table as a csv file

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

I have a data.table that has list values within the columns. Below is the dput:

```
dput(df2)

structure(list(a = list(structure(5594.05118603497, .Names = "a"), 
structure(8877.42723091876, .Names = "a"), structure(2948.95666065332, 
.Names = "a"), 
structure(5312.77623937465, .Names = "a"), structure(676.637044992807, 
.Names = "a"), 
structure(323.104243007498, .Names = "a")), b = 
list(structure(3.90258318853593e-06, .Names = "b"), 
structure(3.89772483584672e-06, .Names = "b"), structure(3.91175458242421e- 
06, .Names = "b"), 
structure(3.90169532031545e-06, .Names = "b"), structure(6.54536728417568e- 
06, .Names = "b"), 
structure(6.59087917747312e-06, .Names = "b")), id = 1:6), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "id"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000220788>)
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
head(df2)

          a            b id
1: 5594.051 3.902583e-06  1
2: 8877.427 3.897725e-06  2
3: 2948.957 3.911755e-06  3
4: 5312.776 3.901695e-06  4
5:  676.637 6.545367e-06  5
6: 323.1042 6.590879e-06  6
```

This looks ok when you see it at first but if you look further into it, this is what it looks like when I want to select a column:

[image]

How do I change df2 to just be a normal dataframe where it doesn't have these extra values within a and b like this? I am trying to write this file to a csv but it will not allow me to because it is saying there are vectors as the values.

Thanks!

Edit:

This was the code that generated the lists:

```
test<-sapply(  split( df , df$ID), 
function(d){ dat <- list2env(d)
nlsfit <- nls( form = y ~ a * (1-exp(-b * x)), data=dat, 
start= list( a=max(dat$y), b=b.start),
           control= control1) 

list(a = coef(nlsfit)[1], b = coef(nlsfit)[2])} )
df1<-as.data.frame(t(test))
```

Comment: Going back one step, what was the code that generated this nested data? If you can eliminate the issue before it even starts, that might be preferable. By the looks of it, you have a `data.table` - was this the result of a `by=` operation?

Comment: just provided the code before this @thelatemail

Comment: The `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000220788>` (and the rownunbers with colons at the side) indicate this is a data.table, not a data.frame. I think you should instead be asking how to write a data.table as a csv file

Comment: Ok thanks just made the change

Comment: I'm going to have to use this output though for future joins and data manipulation so it would be best if this output was in the form of a dataframe without the extra levels like the screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the right package, look at its help page, search for "csv", follow the Usage section:

```
library(data.table)
help(pac=data.table)
fwrite(df2, file="~/test.csv") # for mac, need changing for other OS
```

Another approach might be:

```
 as.data.frame( lapply(df2, unlist) )
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question on writing a csv file. Is there a way to change it into a flat file like this in the R environment or should I just re-upload the csv file after this?

Comment: Those a's and b's are not values; they are names.